# Fit table into page

Tags: tables, scaling, adjustbox

I have been trying to create a (simple) table via tablesgenerator with unsatisfying output so far. I would like to create the following table (Table 4. Summary of Selected....) but it wont fit into my page. Either it is too big or it becomes too small when I use `\resizebox` function or `adjustbox`. [image: table wanted] 
I have looked a lot in this forum and tried many options without success so far. [image] 
The following code plots the table above (Table 3.1). I hope somebody can help me out!
Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}


       \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lllllll@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Model}          & \textbf{Breach morphology}                    & \textbf{Flow}                               & \textbf{Sediment transport capacity}         & \textbf{Geomechanics}                                  & \textbf{Solution method}                         & \textbf{Remarks}                          \\ \midrule
                            & 1D Exner equation                             & 1D St.Venant equations                      & Multiple formulas                            & Longitudinal slope stability                           & Fine difference,uncoupled                        & Overtopping, no lateral erosion           \\
    DEICH\_N1 and DEICH\_N2 & Evolution from 1D/2D Exner quation            & Shallo water equations                      & Nine different formulas availabe             &                                                        & 1D/2D numerical model, uncoupled                 &                                           \\
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Erosion formula from WEPP, USDA              &                                                        & 2D numerical model, uncoupled                    & Validated with Norweigian field tests     \\
                            & Clear-water scour                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Chen and Anderson's formula for erosion rate & 3D slope stability                                     & 2D TVD finite differnce, uncoupled               & Noncohesive dam, overtopping              \\
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formulas for bed-load and suspended load     & Lateral erosion, vertical erosion, and slope stability & 2D finite volume ( Roe and HLL), uncoupled       & Noncohesive levee, overtopping            \\
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formula for bed-load                         & Lateral erosion,vertical erosion, and slope stability  & 2D finite volume (Roe's Riemann solver), coupled & Noncohesive overtopping                   \\
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations with wave-action & Soulsby formula                              & Bed avalanching                                        & 2D finite difference, uncoupled                  & Noncohesive dune and barrier, overtopping \\
                            & 1D/2D Nonequilibrium total-load tranport      & Generelized shallow water equations         & Wu etal. total-load capacity formula         & Lateral erosion and slope stability ( repose angle)    & 1D/2D finite volume (HLL) scheme, coupled        & Noncohesive dam and levee, overtopping    \\
                            & 2D nonequilirbium sediment transport          & Generalized shallow water equations         & Modified Meyer-Peter and Müller bed-load     & Slope stability (repose angle)                         & Finite volume (HLLC) scheme, coupled             & Landslide dam, overtopping                \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! (i) we can't help you if don't know anything about your document. Please extend code snippet to complete small document with this table only beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` and only necessary packages in preamble. (ii) if table is to large to fit in text width, you have only few options: split table, consider to rotating it, locally extend text width (if this is sufficient for table size) ...

Comment: Thank you for that info i extended my code i hope its fine now..

Comment: it's hard to help really. If you put that much data on a page it's either going to be too small to read or you need a larger page. You have the subject knowledge about the table content, can't you split it into two tables, on two pages. (or even more than two)

Comment: hmm it just wonders me that this table appears like this in a pdf so basically it should be possible to obtain the same table in my document as well.. I have also tried rotating or landscape mode... but the table was always not like it is supposed to be... Im probably missing something really basic...

Comment: perhaps you are just looking for `p{3cm}` instead of `l` for your column specifications, so that you get line breaking in the cells?

Comment: perhaps... how would that look like in the code? im sorry im absolutely not so advanced.. thanks a lot for your answer...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the data of your table appears huge and putting this into one table might sacrifice readability of your work. It would be a great thing to do if you can shrink the content of the table a bit or redesign the table. Other than that, I've made a bunch of improvements:

1. I used the `sidewaystable` environment from the rotating package; this will make more room for the table columns.
2. I removed the `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}` and used `tabularx` instead.
3. To avoid too much weird hyphens with full justification, I used `\raggedright`.
4. To gain more space, I changed the default `tabcolsep` from `4pt` to `2pt`.
5. Using `\sffamily` gives also some more space.
6. Finally, using `\small` will save some extra space without sacrificing readability.

The above, as I said before, should be your last resort after both shrinking of content and table redesign fail.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx,rotating}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}

    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \begin{sidewaystable}
    \small\sffamily\centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*7{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Model}          & \textbf{Breach morphology}                    & \textbf{Flow}                               & \textbf{Sediment transport capacity}         & \textbf{Geomechanics}                                  & \textbf{Solution method}                         & \textbf{Remarks}                          \\ \midrule
                            & 1D Exner equation                             & 1D St.Venant equations                      & Multiple formulas                            & Longitudinal slope stability                           & Fine difference,uncoupled                        & Overtopping, no lateral erosion           \\
    DEICH\_N1 and DEICH\_N2 & Evolution from 1D/2D Exner quation            & Shallo water equations                      & Nine different formulas availabe             &                                                        & 1D/2D numerical model, uncoupled                 &                                           \\
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Erosion formula from WEPP, USDA              &                                                        & 2D numerical model, uncoupled                    & Validated with Norweigian field tests     \\
                            & Clear-water scour                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Chen and Anderson's formula for erosion rate & 3D slope stability                                     & 2D TVD finite differnce, uncoupled               & Noncohesive dam, overtopping              \\
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formulas for bed-load and suspended load     & Lateral erosion, vertical erosion, and slope stability & 2D finite volume ( Roe and HLL), uncoupled       & Noncohesive levee, overtopping            \\
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formula for bed-load                         & Lateral erosion,vertical erosion, and slope stability  & 2D finite volume (Roe's Riemann solver), coupled & Noncohesive overtopping                   \\
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations with wave-action & Soulsby formula                              & Bed avalanching                                        & 2D finite difference, uncoupled                  & Noncohesive dune and barrier, overtopping \\
                            & 1D/2D Nonequilibrium total-load tranport      & Generelized shallow water equations         & Wu etal. total-load capacity formula         & Lateral erosion and slope stability ( repose angle)    & 1D/2D finite volume (HLL) scheme, coupled        & Noncohesive dam and levee, overtopping    \\
                            & 2D nonequilirbium sediment transport          & Generalized shallow water equations         & Modified Meyer-Peter and Müller bed-load     & Slope stability (repose angle)                         & Finite volume (HLLC) scheme, coupled             & Landslide dam, overtopping                \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
    \end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. The posts were really helpfull !

Answer (score 3):

Assuming  that:

- text width can be increased (by use `\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}`)
- the cell contents can be broken into more lines
- font size of table content is `\footnotesize`

then you obtain:

[image]

if this is not satisfactory, than you should consider above comments.

**edit:** i recognise that to the first version of answer i forgot add code example (*mwe*). it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\footnotesize\sffamily
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}*7{R}@{}}
    \toprule
\textbf{Model}
    & \textbf{Breach morphology}
        & \textbf{Flow}
            & \textbf{Sediment transport capacity}
                & \textbf{Geomechanics}
                    & \textbf{Solution method}
                        & \textbf{Remarks}                                          \\
    \midrule
    & 1D Exner equation                     & 1D St.Venant equations
    & Multiple formulas                     & Longitudinal slope stability
    & Fine difference,uncoupled             & Overtopping, no lateral erosion       \\
    \addlinespace
DEICH\_N1 and DEICH\_N2
    & Evolution from 1D/2D Exner quation    & Shallo water equations
    & Nine different formulas availabe      &                                                        & 1D/2D numerical model, uncoupled      &                                       \\
    \addlinespace
    & 2D Exner equation                     & 2D shallow water equations
    & Erosion formula from WEPP, USDA       &
    & 2D numerical model, uncoupled         & Validated with Norweigian field tests \\
    \addlinespace
    & Clear-water scour                     & 2D shallow water equations
    & Chen and Anderson's formula for erosion rate
                                            & 3D slope stability                                    
    & 2D TVD finite differnce, uncoupled    & Noncohesive dam, overtopping          \\
    \addlinespace
    & 2D Exner equation                     & 2D shallow water equations
    & Formulas for bed-load and suspended load
                                    & Lateral erosion, vertical erosion, and slope stability
    & 2D finite volume ( Roe and HLL), uncoupled
                                    & Noncohesive levee, overtopping                \\
    \addlinespace
    & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation
                                    & 2D shallow water equations
    & Formula for bed-load          & Lateral erosion,vertical erosion, and slope stability
    & 2D finite volume (Roe's Riemann solver), coupled
                                    & Noncohesive overtopping                       \\
    \addlinespace
    & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation
                                    & 2D shallow water equations with wave-action
    & Soulsby formula               & Bed avalanching
    & 2D finite difference, uncoupled       & Noncohesive dune and barrier, overtopping \\
    \addlinespace
    & 1D/2D Nonequilibrium total-load tranport
                                    & Generelized shallow water equations
    & Wu etal. total-load capacity formula
                                    & Lateral erosion and slope stability ( repose angle)
    & 1D/2D finite volume (HLL) scheme, coupled
                                    & Noncohesive dam and levee, overtopping    \\
    \addlinespace
    & 2D nonequilirbium sediment transport
                                    & Generalized shallow water equations
    & Modified Meyer-Peter and Müller bed-load
                                    & Slope stability (repose angle)
    & Finite volume (HLLC) scheme, coupled
                                    & Landslide dam, overtopping                \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can't widen the text block substantially and if you don't want to (or aren't allowed to) switch to a much smaller font size, you will have to switch to a `longtable` environment, as the material simply won't fit on a single page.

[image]

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\newlength\firstcolwidth
\settowidth\firstcolwidth{DEICH\_N1}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt} % default: 6pt
\newlength\othercolwidth
\setlength\othercolwidth{\dimexpr\textwidth-\firstcolwidth-12\tabcolsep\relax}
\setlength\othercolwidth{\dimexpr\othercolwidth/6\relax}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{@{} p{\firstcolwidth} 
    *{6}{P{\othercolwidth}} @{}}
    \caption{My caption} \label{tab:my-label}\\
    \toprule
Model & Breach morphology & Flow & Sediment transport capacity & Geomechanics & Solution method & Remarks \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l@{}}{Table \ref{tab:my-label}, continued}\\ \addlinespace
\toprule
Model & Breach morphology & Flow & Sediment transport capacity & Geo\-mechanics & Solution method & Remarks \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}r@{}}{continued on following page}\\
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

                            & 1D Exner equation                             & 1D St. Venant equations                      & Multiple formulas                            & Longitudinal slope stability                           & Fine difference, uncoupled                        & Overtopping, no lateral erosion           \\ \addlinespace
DEICH\_N1 and DEICH\_N2     & Evolution from 1D/2D Exner equation            & Shallow water equations                      & Nine different formulas available             &                                                        & 1D/2D numerical model, uncoupled                 &                                           \\ \addlinespace
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Erosion formula from WEPP, USDA              &                                                        & 2D numerical model, uncoupled                    & Validated with Norwegian field tests     \\ \addlinespace
                            & Clear-water scour                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Chen and Anderson's formula for erosion rate & 3D slope stability                                     & 2D TVD finite differnce, uncoupled               & Noncohesive dam, overtopping              \\ \addlinespace
                            & 2D Exner equation                             & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formulas for bed-load and suspended load     & Lateral erosion,  vertical erosion, and slope stability & 2D finite volume (Roe and HLL), uncoupled       & Noncohesive levee, overtopping            \\ \addlinespace
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations                  & Formula for bed-load                         & Lateral erosion, vertical erosion, and slope stability  & 2D finite volume (Roe's Riemann solver), coupled & Noncohesive overtopping                   \\ %\addlinespace
                            & 2D nonequilibrium sediment transport equation & 2D shallow water equations with wave-action & Soulsby formula                              & Bed avalanching                                        & 2D finite difference, uncoupled                  & Noncohesive dune and barrier, overtopping \\ \addlinespace
                            & 1D/2D Nonequilibrium total-load tranport      & Generalized shallow water equations         & Wu et~al.\ total-load capacity formula         & Lateral erosion and slope stability (repose angle)    & 1D/2D finite volume (HLL) scheme, coupled        & Noncohesive dam and levee, overtopping    \\ \addlinespace
                            & 2D non\-equilib\-rium sediment transport          & Generalized shallow water equations         & Modified Meyer-Peter and Müller bed-load     & Slope stability (repose angle)                         & Finite volume (HLLC) scheme, coupled             & Landslide dam, overtopping                \\ 
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```